# Map Reduce Simple score aggregating for common queries

Tags: python, algorithm, mapreduce

One of my mapper produces some logs distributed in files like part-0, part-1, part-2 etc. Now each of these have some queries and some associated data for that query:

```
part-0

q             score         
1 ben 10      4.01
horse shoe    5.96
...

part-1

1 ben 10        3.23
horse shoe      2.98
....

and so on for part-2,3 etc.
```

Now the same query q i.e. "1 ben 10" above resides in part-1, part-2 etc.

Now I have to write a map reduce phase where in I can collect the same queries and aggregate (add up) their scores.

My mapper function can be an identity and in the reduce I will be accomplishing this task.

Output would be:

```
q       aggScore
1 ben 10    7.24
horse shoe  8.96
...
```

Seems to be a simple task but I am not able to think of as to how can I proceed with this (Read a lot but not really able to proceed). I can think in terms of generic Algorithm problem wherein first I will collect the common queries and than add up their scores.

Any help with some hints of pythonic solution or Algorithm (map reduce) would really be appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) What method are you using to read from the file, store the data, manipulate it, and then display it to the user?

Comment: I am using Hadoop Streaming. The input comes from stdin an goes to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the MapReduce solution:

Map input: Each input file (part-0, part-1, part-2, ...) can be input to individual (separate) map task.

foreach input line in the input file,
Mapper emits `<q,aggScore>`. If there are multiple scores for a query in a single file, Map will sum them all up, otherwise if we know that each query will appear in each file just once, map can be an identity function emitting `<q,aggScore>` for each input line as is.

Reducer input is in the form `<q,list<aggScore1,aggScore2,...>` The Reducer operation is similar to well-known MapReduce example of `wordcount`. If you are using Hadoop, you can use the following method for Reducer.

```
public void reduce(Text q, Iterable<IntWritable> aggScore, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   int sum = 0;
   for (IntWritable val : aggScore) {
      sum += val.get();
   }
   context.write(q, new IntWritable(sum));
}
```

The method will sum all `aggScores` for a particular`q` and give you the desired output. The python code for the reducer should look something like this (Here `q` is the key and the list of `aggScores` is the values) :

```
def reduce(self, key, values, output, reporter):
    sum = 0
    while values.hasNext():
        sum += values.next().get()
    output.collect(key, IntWritable(sum))
```